# virtual box not installing

Tags: virtualbox

virtual box 6.0  not installing in Ubuntu 16.04 and while pressing the option install it is installing but after few seconds it is coming out and showing the option install option again

Comment: Where did you get Virtualbox from?

Comment: Your question lack of details. Would you try to edit your question to specify what your are trying to do exactly? Is it a VirtualBox from Ubuntu repositories? Downloaded from the internet? If yes, where and which version?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try downloading it off there website and installing it?
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Because your on Ubuntu click `Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 / Debian 1` or `Ubuntu 16.04`
Then run the installer that downloads